# Combine fields belonging to objects in an array

Tags: typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm struggling with a basic task. I have an array of objects like this:

```
// Dummy data
let boop = [
    {a: 5, b: 10},
    {a: 7, c: 8},
    {a: 6, b: 7, c: 9}
];
```

and I'd like to turn it into this

```
//Desired result: {a: [5, 7, 6], b: [10, null, 7], c: [null, 8, 9]};
```

Notice that if the value if missing from an object, it is denoted with null. I expect that first I'll need to know all the fields I plan to populate, so start with this:

```
// Get unique keys
let uniqueKeys = Object.keys(boop.reduce((result, row) => {
         return Object.assign(result, row);
}, {}))
```

Next, I create an object to hold my results.

```
// To hold result
var result: Record<string, any[]> = {};
```

Finally, I iterate over my array and for each object I try to extract the field (if it exists) and push it into an array within my final object. If the field is `undefined` I use `null` and push that instead.

```
boop.forEach(item => { // Loop through each item
    for(let field of uniqueKeys){ // Loop through each field for each item
        let value = item[field as keyof typeof item]; // Get value (if it exists!)
        value ??= null;
        result[field].push(value);
    } 
})
```

This produces the error:

> [ERR]: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'result[field].push')

The issue seems to be the push, as when I use `result[field] = [1, 2, 3];` I can assign values to my object no problem.

How do I correctly push values into each array within my object?

Comment: Iterate over the array, get the keys, put them in a `Set`. Iterate over the array again, and for each iteration, iterate the set, insert the key in Map, and push the corresponding values in the `Map`'s key.  It's a bit hard to understand but this is only a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into a similar issue, the solution is that I needed to initialize my object with empty arrays first. For example,

```
for(let field of uniqueKeys) {
    result[field] = [];
}
```

---

The full code is therefore,

```
// Dummy data
let boop = [
    {a: 5, b: 10},
    {a: 7, c: 8},
    {a: 6, b: 7, c: 9}
];

// Get unique keys
let uniqueKeys = Object.keys(boop.reduce((result, row) => {
         return Object.assign(result, row);
}, {})) 

// To hold result
var result: Record<string, any[]> = {};

// Initialise arrays in object 
for(let field of uniqueKeys) {
    result[field] = [];
}

boop.forEach(item => { // Loop through each item
    for(let field of uniqueKeys){ // Loop through each field for each item
        let value = item[field as keyof typeof item]; // Get value (if it exists!)
        result[field].push(value);
    } 
})

console.log(result);
```

Result:

```
[LOG]: {
  "a": [
    5,
    7,
    6
  ],
  "b": [
    10,
    undefined,
    7
  ],
  "c": [
    undefined,
    8,
    9
  ]
}
```

Not perfect, as I have `undefined` instead of `null`, but that's another issue...